# Can't place many selectors in one code

Tags: css-selectors, double

```
::moz-selection, ::selection {}
```

This is not working.

I don't want to place many selector functions, so I am asking how to convert them in one style sheet.

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that show or reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You must repeat the selector CSS for Firefox, as the browser will not read it if you put both together in the same code. This is often the case with browser support and prefixes, for backwards and cross browser compatibility.

Working example:

```
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

::selection {
  color: red; 
  background: yellow;
}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp

You may wish to consider writing PostCSS with Autoprefixer, this will compile into "::selection" into "::selection" and automatically add a "::-moz-selection" on the compiled CSS version for you. This keeps your code cleaner when maintaining it, as the browser prefixes exist in the compiled version only.

Comment: But can't I make it short because if you have many of them like input[text], textarea..... and you have to place for them always another selector, that is hard....

Comment: @Anatoly ::selection { } will be the highlight colour for everything on the page. Not sure why you would need to do this for input[text], textarea etc?